# Why i cannot import in react it saya eslint error no unused vars . even if i dont see an error i cannot see anything rendered

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite

Why i cannot import in react it says eslint error no unused vars . even if i dont see an error i cannot see anything rendered

// Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

// App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar"; // Import the Navbar component

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar /> {/* Include the Navbar component */}
      <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
      {/* Rest of your content */}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Can anyone help me to find the issue

Comment: Please add the exact and complete error from eslint in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the codes you added, you should add screenshot of the error + your folder structure and other screenshots to know why your page is not rendering